# load xml which includes unescaped characters PHP

Tags: php, xml, regex

I'm new with PHP :)

I'm trying to load XML which includes unescaped characters. I want to use REGEX. Can anyone tell me, how to do it properly?

This is my simple XML file:

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<test>
    <url>http://example.com?T=2&P=1</url>
</test>
```

and my code:

```
$test = file_get_contents( __DIR__ . '/../test/test.xml' );
$objXml = simplexml_load_string( $test );
var_dump( $objXml );
```

and i receive this error:

```
"simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 3: parser error : EntityRef: expecting ';'"
```

any ideas how can I get it?

Comment: why you don't use simplexml_load_file()

Answer (score 1):

Just try to encapslulate data in XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<test>
    <url><![CDATA[http://example.com?T=2&P=1]]></url>
</test>
```

Also take in consideration @Rakesh Sharma comment to use simplexml_load_file()

[Info about CDATA](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp)